# Summing instead of overriding values in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, dictionary-comprehension

When the keys in a dictionary comprehension is the same, I want their values to be added up. For example,

```
>>> dct = {-1: 1, 0: 2, 1: 3}
>>> {k**2: v for k, v in dct.items()}
{1: 3, 0: 2}
```

However, what I want to get in this case is `{1: 4, 0: 2}`, because both the square of 1 and -1 is 1, and 1 + 3 = 4.

Clearly, I can do it with a for loop, but is there a shorthand?

Comment: Just use a for-loop. Or a `collections.Counter` object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The Counter won't work, will it?

Comment: @DYZ it would work the same way as your defaultdict answer, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am a slow-thinker today. Why don't you post your answer? I am curious.

Comment: @DYZ `counts = Counter(); for k, v in old.items(): counts[k**2] += v` I would use either a `Counter` or a `defaultdict`, depending on which i've already imported :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, ok. You use a counter as a defaultdict, not as a counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a shorthand version, since your comprehension would need to keep track of the current state which isn't doable. Like you said, the answer is a for loop:

```
old = {-1: 1, 0: 2, 1:3}
new = {}
for k, v in old.items():
    new[k**2] = new.get(k**2, 0) + v
```

The trick using the `dict.get` method I saw somewhere in the Python docs. It does the same thing as:

```
if k**2 in new:
   new[k**2] += v
else:
   new[k**2] = v
```

But this variation uses the `get` method which returns a default 0 which is added on to the value that will be assigned (when the key doesn't exist). Since it is 0, and the values are numbers being added, 0 has no effect. By contrast, if you needed to get the product, you'd use 1 as the default as starting off with 0 will mean that you never increase the value.

In addition, the latter, more verbose, method shown above evaluates `k**2` twice each cycle which uses up computation. To make it use 1 calculation would require *another* line of code which in my opinion isn't worth the time when the `get` method is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

One of the fastest ways to calculate the sums is to use `defaultdict` - a self-initializing dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in old.items():
    new[k**2] += v
```